# Grid content is clipped only in ScrollView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML and code behind.  For some reason, the grid contained within the ScrollView is clipped (the third row is not displayed).  I would have expected that everything fits on one screen since the ListView scrolls vertically and could be compacted a bit more.

If I remove the ScrollView and the grid is inline with the other elements, everything displays as expected.

Why is the third row being clipped, and how can I get it to always display?

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0 but can also reproduce this with latest 3.1.0, and this is seen in UWP, Android and iOS.

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinScrollView"
    x:Name="TheMainPage"            
    x:Class="XamarinScrollView.MainPage">

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference TheMainPage}">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StringValue}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StringValue}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StringValue}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StringValue, StringFormat='String Value: {0}'}" IsVisible="{Binding HasStringValue}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StringValue, StringFormat='String Value: {0}'}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StringValue, StringFormat='String Value: {0}'}" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="2">
            <BoxView.Color>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                    <On Platform="Android">White</On>
                    <On Platform="iOS">Black</On>
                    <On Platform="UWP">Black</On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </BoxView.Color>
        </BoxView>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DateValue, StringFormat='Date Value: {0:g}'}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DateValue, StringFormat='Date Value: {0:g}'}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding StringValue, StringFormat='String Value: {0}'}" />

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateValue, StringFormat='Date Value: {0:g}'}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateValue, StringFormat='Date Value: {0:g}'}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateValue, StringFormat='Date Value: {0:g}'}" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
        <Frame Margin="2">
            <Frame.BorderColor>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                    <On Platform="Android">White</On>
                    <On Platform="iOS">Black</On>
                    <On Platform="UWP">Black</On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </Frame.BorderColor>

            <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,20">
                <Label Text="String Value" />
                <Label Text="{Binding StringValue}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Margin="2">
            <Frame.BorderColor>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                    <On Platform="Android">White</On>
                    <On Platform="iOS">Black</On>
                    <On Platform="UWP">Black</On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </Frame.BorderColor>

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding StringValue1}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding StringValue2}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding StringValue3}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinScrollView {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string StringValue => "This is a string";

        public DateTime DateValue => DateTime.Now;

        public bool HasStringValue => true;

        private readonly List<ListItem> listItems = new List<ListItem> { 
            new ListItem(),
        };
        public IEnumerable<ListItem> ListItems => listItems;
    }

    public sealed class ListItem { 
        public string StringValue1 => "1. This is a string";
        public string StringValue2 => "2. This is a string";
        public string StringValue3 => "3. This is a string";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting MinimumHeightRequest on both the ScrollView and the contained GridView seems to resolve this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ScrollView, however, you do not wan't for elements to be clipped. Your solution is to give a HeightRequest to the ScrollView.

Comment: Since this answer led me to the right one, I'm giving the bounty.

Comment: What did you end up using @Andy?

Comment: I posted my own answer, but setting *Mimimum*HeightRequest on both the grid and scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of items in the ListView, the ScrollView will shrink so the ListView has enough space to show its items.

Even though your grid has `Auto` rows and will create rows to fit the content being shown, the `ScrollView` will shrink to a certain point. The `Grid` still has the amount of space needed for its contents, but the ScrollView is only showing what it can for the space the **ScrollView** is given in the `StackLayout`. Since you are only allowing `Horizontal` orientation for your ScrollView, that is why you aren't able to scroll to see the last row of your Grid.

Comment: This seems to happen though even with only one item in the list view, and plenty of space in the lower portion of the screen.   The intent of the scrollview is to somehow get the right column off screen so the user can swipe back and forth to view the contents of the 1st & 2nd column, but implementing that will be another question.

Comment: Stack layouts don't expand each child to fill the maximum space. Try setting the ScollView `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand`. Does that work?

Comment: `FillAndExpand` didn't work.  The outer-most `StackLayout` is already taking the entire page; even if I maximize, the last row of the `Grid` is still clipped.  I do think it has to do with the `ListView`; it seems to have some large minimum size even though there's only one item.  Bizarre because it can scroll so it shouldn't need as much space as its taking.